# Can 2 eggs come from ONLY 1 ovary?

Tags: pregnancy, twins

I only have 1 ovary due to previous pregnancy and was told that, that pregnancy was a twin pregnancy. I know I can have identical twins but I wanna know the odds of fraternal twins.

Comment: It would seem to be obviously yes, since it's possible to have fraternal triplets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_birth#Triplets  I would guess that the odds for you having fraternal twins are about the same as a woman with two ovaries having triplets: about 1 in 1000.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is yes, you can have fraternal twins. I don't know the likelihood of this happening, and I don't think there is any literature on it in the scientific community.

There is a phenomenon called superovulation, which is where more than one ova (egg) is released during a cycle. The classic model of one egg being released per cycle is still being investigated, and it is possible that it will be found to be true.

I had assumed (me not being an expert on fertility) that such a phenomenon was uncommon, but it seems that it is more the norm than not.

The most recent and most complete study I could find on this is an article on the development of follicles (pre-egg phase) in normal women from Canada. In the article they found that despite the current model of single waves of development and ova release, in most women there are at least two waves of follicular development per intraovulatory interval (IOI)<sup>1</sup>.

> Nonrandom  changes  in  the  number  of  follicles >5mm and the diameter of follicles >6 mm (Non-Identity Method) were observed in all 50 women during the IOI, indicating a wave pattern of follicle development. Thirty-four of the 50 women (68%) exhibited two waves of follicle development; the  remaining  16  women  (32%)  exhibited  three  waves  of follicle development...  ...None  of  the  women  evaluated  exhibited  only  a single wave of follicle development during the IOI.

They didn't go so far as to say that each wave resulted in ovulation, despite several editorials claiming this was may be case in very reputable scientific journals (e.g. this [British Medical Journal](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1126506/) one).  In fact they say that only the final wave in each IOI is ovulatory (anovulation being without ovulation):

> The final wave of the cycle was ovulatory and the preceding waves were anovulatory in all 50 women.

Of note is that for women who have undergone unilateral (one-sided) [oophorectomy](https://www.mayoclinic.org/tests-procedures/oophorectomy/about/pac-20385030), the remaining ovary seems to compensate to some extent, producing regular menstrual cycles. I haven't been able to find out if there is an egg released from the one side each cycle or not, but I think most women [don't necessarily alternate sides between cycles](https://academic.oup.com/humrep/article/15/4/752/706405).

1. [Baerwald *et al*](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/12849812/)., A new model for ovarian follicular development
   during the human menstrual cycle. 2003. Fertility and Sterility 80(1).